# Should I renew Google Domain at low yearly price before the transfer to Squarespace?

Tags: domains, google-domains, squarespace

So I'm using Google Domains with yearly renewal to host my static GitHub pages website and I was wondering if it would be a good idea to renew the domain for the next 9 years (which is the max limit) at the current price of approx $10/year before all domains are transferred to Squarespace? I looked up Squarespace pricing and I saw that their [Personal plan](https://www.squarespace.com/pricing) starts at **$16/mo**. Does anyone know if Squarespace would honor the domain hosting for that period if I were to do this? The squarespace pricing is way too steep for me.

Comment: Why are you transferring the domain if the price is so much higher?  You can use squarespace for webhosting without using them as a domain registrar.

Comment: I should've been clearer. Squarespace has purchased Google Domains registrations so the domains will transfer in maybe a few months. I've only recently setup my website and didn't want to have to do too many changes. Square space provides hosting at the price that I mentioned above with a free domain on their personal plan. I'm apprehensive at paying a higher cost so soon since I've only recently setup a static website and won't be using the thrills and frills offered by squarespace as much.

Comment: I hadn't heard that news!   The price you linked above is for web hosting at square space.  They have a way to pay for domain registration without web hosting.  https://www.squarespace.com/domain-name-search shows that current prices per year for `.com` domains is $20.

Answer (score 1):

Discussed with both Google Domain and Square space support and SS mentioned that they will honor the validity of existing Google Domains.